# Map/access array inside object on Pojo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok, pojo

How can I access and map an array inside an object on Pojo Spring Boot?

This is what I wanted to map

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "customerId": "0434556574",
            "paymentCode": "90501"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to classes to match the JSON structure:

```java
public class CustomersData {
    private List<Customer> customers;

    // Constructor, getter and setter
}
```

```java
public class Customer {
    private String customerId;
    private String paymentCode;

    // Constructor, getter and setter
}
```

Important thing is to make sure your JSON properties name matches the attributes name in your Java classes (thus avoiding explicit mapping between them).

Answer (score 0):

Hi There are lot's of utility libraries you can convert JSON to required java class so that you can instantiate in right way.
Example based on your input:

-----------------------------------com.example.Customer.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"customerId",
"paymentCode"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Customer {

@JsonProperty("customerId")
private String customerId;
@JsonProperty("paymentCode")
private String paymentCode;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("customerId")
public String getCustomerId() {
return customerId;
}

@JsonProperty("customerId")
public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
this.customerId = customerId;
}

@JsonProperty("paymentCode")
public String getPaymentCode() {
return paymentCode;
}

@JsonProperty("paymentCode")
public void setPaymentCode(String paymentCode) {
this.paymentCode = paymentCode;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"customers"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("customers")
private List<Customer> customers = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
return customers;
}

@JsonProperty("customers")
public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
this.customers = customers;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Reference :[jsontopojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)